# Python split string by urls with and without a href

Tags: python, split

Actually my script working as expected (split string by url and maintain other text also) and put inside a list:

```
import re
s = 'This is my tweet check it out http://www.example.com/blah and http://blabla.com'
result = re.split(r'(https?://\S+)', s)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['This is my tweet check it out ', 'http://www.example.com/blah', ' and ', 'http://blabla.com', '']
```

Now I'm stuck in another problem: sometimes I get urls as html, or mixed text+html, and url are like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/full/path/to/product/">https://shorted.com/FJAKS</a>
```

`href` with full url, value between `<a>...</a>` the **shortened** url.

So I can receive a string like this to manipulate:

```
s = 'This is an html link: <a href="http://www.example.com/full/path/to/product/">https://shorted.com/FJAKS</a> and this is a text url: http://blabla.com'
```

I'd like to get the same logic for my function, but If I use:

```
result = re.split(r'(https?://\S+)', s)
print(result)
```

like before, I get this (WRONG):

```
['This is an html link: <a href="', 'http://www.example.com/full/path/to/product/">https://shorted.com/FJAKS</a>', ' and this is a text url: ', 'http://blabla.com', '']
```

But i'd like to get a situation like this (If it is an HTML, get all `a` tag):

Output expected:

```
['This is an html link: ', '<a href="http://www.example.com/full/path/to/product/">https://shorted.com/FJAKS</a>', ' and this is a text url: ', 'http://blabla.com', '']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
s = 'This is an html link: <a href="http://www.example.com/full/path/to/product/">https://shorted.com/FJAKS</a> and this is a text url: http://blabla.com'
result = re.split(r'((?:<a href=")?https?://\S+[^\s,.:;])', s)
print(result)
```

The key is the addition of `(?:<a href=")?`. `(?:)` means a group that isn't captured; it's useful so that the `?` applies to that entire unit instead of a single character.

Note: a URL at the beginning or end creates a blank list item. If you'd like to remove those, try:

```
result = list(filter((None, result)))
```

EDIT: Added `[^\s,.:;]` to the end of the match. The `^` ensures we'll *avoid* matching the final character if it's any of the specified characters. This avoids links from gobbling up punctuation directly after them, like commas.

Comment: `re.split(r'((?:<a)?(?: href=")?https?://\S+)', s)` to take care of the shortened form as well.

Comment: Thanks to all. I'm not good with reg exp. Anyone can suggest a good tutorial for very very newbies?

Comment: It may seem intimidatingly thorough, but honestly I heartily recommend the official Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @CrazyChucky Hi, sorry I tried your code with another string but i get a little error. The string is: `This is an html link: <a href="http://www.example.com/full/path/to/product/">https://shortedlink.com</a> and this is a text url: http://blabla.com, another https://www.blabla.com and another <a href="http://www.blabla.com/test">TEST</a>` .....i get this as url: `http://blabla.com,` <--- see the comma

Comment: @itajackass Edited.